# How to take out the first component of an array when it doesn't have any contents

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, nsarray

I made a textview that is bulleted only.  It works just like a bulleted list in word.  Now I am making an array using this code to separate strings by a bullet point (\u2022)

```
//get the text inside the textView
NSString *textContents = myTextView.text;

//make the array
NSArray *bulletedArray = [textContents componentsSeparatedByString:@"\u2022"];

//print out array 
NSLog(@"%@",bulletedArray);
```

It works perfectly with separating the text into components by bullet points but it keeps the first line that has nothing in it. So when it prints out it looks like this.

```
"",
"Here is my first statement\n\n",
"Here is my second statement.\n\n",
"This is my third statement. "
```

The very first component of the array is "" (nothing). Is there a way to avoid adding components that equal nil?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, this is the way the `componentsSeparatedBy...` methods of `NSString` work:

> Adjacent occurrences of the separator characters produce empty strings in the result. Similarly, if the string begins or ends with separator characters, the first or last substring, respectively, is empty.

Since you know that the first element will always be empty, you can make a sub-array starting at element `1`:

```
NSArray *bulletedArray = [textContents componentsSeparatedByString:@"\u2022"];
NSUInteger len = bulletedArray.count;
if (bulletedArray.count) {
    bulletedArray = [bulletedArray subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(1, len-1)];
}
```

Alternatively, you can use `substringFromIndex:` to chop off the initial bullet character from the string before passing it to the `componentsSeparatedByString:` method:

```
NSArray *bulletedArray = [
    [textContents substringFromIndex:[textContents rangeOfString:@"\u2022"].location+1]
    componentsSeparatedByString:@"\u2022"];
```

Comment: you used count in your if statement, what do you mean by that?

Comment: @Craig Oops, it was supposed to be `bulletedArray.count`. The idea is to avoid an exception when the input is empty.

Answer (score 0):

```
[[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[textContents componentsSeparatedByString:@"\u2022"]] removeObjectIdenticalTo:@""];
```

that should do the trick

Comment: what do I do with my previous array I made called bulletedArray? Are you saying that I should make another array?  You are using arrayWithArray but using the text inside of my textview and not an array.  textContents is a string.

Comment: textContents is a string, but the `componentsSeparatedByString:` method returns an array, so you can make a mutable array with that and remove all instances of `@""` from the mutable array.

Answer (score 0):

while your bulleted list has always a bullet on index 1, you can simply cut the first index out of the string:

```
//get the text inside the textView
if (myTextView.text.length > 1) {
    NSString *textContents =[myTextView.text substringFromIndex:2];

    //make the array
    NSArray *bulletedArray = [textContents componentsSeparatedByString:@"\u2022"];

    //print out array    
    NSLog(@"%@",bulletedArray);     
}
```

of course you should avoid having an empty text, while this would cause an arrayOutOfBounds Exception.